# twitter4j status in twitter have image but there no media entities

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I am trying to use twitter4j to get twitter user timeline statuses and the information about them. The problem is that in twitter there are images attached to some of the statuses but twitter4j returns empty media entities. Here is my code:

```
for (Status status : twStatuses) {
    String Iurl = status.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
    twitterLink.add("https://twitter.com/" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + "/status/" + status.getId());
    twitterText.add(status.getText());
    ExtendedMediaEntity[] media = status.getExtendedMediaEntities(); //get the media entities from the status

    if (media.length == 0) {
        twitterImage.add("0");
    } else {
        for (ExtendedMediaEntity mediaEntity : media) {
            if (mediaEntity.getMediaURL().equals("")) {
                twitterImage.add("0");
            } else {
                twitterImage.add(mediaEntity.getMediaURL());
            }
        }
    }

    twitterDate.add(status.getCreatedAt().toString());   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember, I used it like this before: *edit:This was for getting 1 image only.*

```
for(MediaEntity me : status.getMediaEntities()){
    if(me.getMediaURLHttps() != null)//also check blank
        twitterImage.add(me.getMediaURLHttps());
}
```

To fetch all media [entities](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/extended-entities-object)(maximum 4 photos || 1 video || 1 GIF)

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
List < Status > statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();

for (Status status: statuses) {
 ExtendedMediaEntity[] extendedMediaEntities = status.getExtendedMediaEntities();

 for (ExtendedMediaEntity eme: extendedMediaEntities) {
  if (eme.getMediaURLHttps() != null) { //also check blank
   if (eme.getType.equals("photo"))
    twitterImage.add(me.getMediaURLHttps());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: OK i tried it but still the same thing happens. I get only one image from 8 images. I am starting to thing there is some kind of problem with twitter4j, i have researched a lot but didnt find other people with this kind of issue, but still i am concerned. Also i have noticed in some twitter timelines from 10 images i get 7 or 8. In some i barely get 1 or 2. I will be thankful for any kind of information or help because i dont know what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, yes MediaEntity returns only the first image attached. I needed to return 1 image for my app that's why I wrote what I could remember. You should use ExtendedMediaEntity as you're already doing. But in documentation it says maximum "Tweets can only have one type of media attached to it. For photos, up to four photos can be attached. For videos and GIFs, one can be attached.".   Plus, " 'media' represents media elements uploaded with the Tweet". There may be image URLs (with previews) shared within the tweet. Which you won't get via ExtendedMediaEntity.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response now it is more clear to me.